Payment Processing Webhooks Table Empty
So far I've set up a contribution page that uses Stripe checkout to process payments. On the Stripe Dashboard/API the payments are successful. However, my member gets added to the database but the status says Pending(Incomplete transaction). I thought this was due to the cron not running the scheduled jobs so I executed the update memberships job manually and it still says the status is pending. So I went into the Payment Processors Webhooks table and noticed that it was empty after loading the right credentials. My assumption is that CiviCRM is not receiving the webhooks from Stripe. Does anyone know how I can go about fixing this?

Did you see Pradeep's reply to your earlier question. It seems like the same question: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/48391/181

I've tried that and it doesn't work.

In stripe, on the developer tab, there's a section for webhooks. Can you see if there are any in there? If there are and you click on them you can check their logs for errors.

So everything works my webhooks are all success and my payments. My API endpoints show me the success including the civicrm id and customer and all those details. The only issue I'm having is getting the member to update. I know it's not getting the webhooks from stripe since my table says 0 webhooks beside the payment processor. Although I added the right webhook secret. Did I need to add a site URL in this?

I'm not sure if what you're calling api endpoints is the same as webhooks. There's a "tab" at the top of the stripe portal that says "Developers". Click that. Then you get a set of tabs Overview, API Keys, Webhooks, etc... Click on Webhooks. You should see one for your civi payment processor. If you click on it, you'll see logs for it. Look at the Response section on the right side and look for errors.

Is the scheduled job also enabled/running to for webhooks (Process PaymentProcessor Webhooks)?
